# faster nested for loops for all pair of rows in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, signal-processing

I have a numpy array, which is basically phase of oscillations recorded for 256 channels sampled at 1000 Hz for an hour. As a result, I have got a numpy array size of `256 x 5000000`. I want to calculate `Phase locking value` for all pair of channels (rows). Phase locking value is a measure of how coupled the oscillations are. Here is a method that works, but is obviously time-consuming. I've 128Gb RAM available.

```
x = np.array([]) # 256 x 5000000
Nchans = 256
op = np.empty([Nchans, Nchans])
op[:] = np.nan
for a in range(Nchans):
    for b in range(Nchans):
        op[a,b] = np.abs(np.nansum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1)*(x[a] - x[b]))))/x.shape[1]
```

Is there any way I can speed up this calculation?

Comment: Can you say more about what result you're trying to compute? As written the best way to optimize this would be to skip the loops and only compute the last iteration, because every other iteration is discarded: `complex_phase_diff = np.abs(np.nansum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1)*(x[255] - x[255]))))/x.shape[1]`

Comment: Sorry for that. Added my changes to the scripts. I need all the phasediff calculation to run on all combinations of row

Comment: Do you *really* need to create a list with 1_280_000_000 items in Python? This does not seems reasonable at all, especially since each item is a Python object that needs to be allocated, freed, reference counted and takes at least 32 bytes, not to mention the reference of typically 8 bytes in the list. In the end you need at least 47.7 GiB of RAM (optimistic lower-bound).... Storing this in a Numpy array is better (19 GiB) but still not really reasonable for a Python script... Not storing `op` is certainly a good idea. This means you need to still tell us more about the use-case.

Comment: okay, I added more details and hopefully it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
complex_phase_diff = np.abs(np.nansum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1) * np.subtract.outer(x[a], x[b])), axis=1)) / x.shape[1]
```

Comment: throws memory error

Comment: @deathracer This is not surprising regarding the amount of memory use by the initial code which should *also throws a memory error* on any mainstream machine. You provided no information about the running environment so they could not know if this fits your needs...

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?